# Dalitz plot of a top quark decay?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, experimental-technique

What would a [Dalitz plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalitz_plot) of a top quark decay look like? I haven't been able to find any in the literature, which is dominated by LHCb hadron spectroscopy, at much smaller masses than the top... perhaps that's a limitation?

Considering the hadronic decay of a top to $q'qb$, either as a three-body decay with an off-shell $W^\pm$ boson, or with an intermediate short-lived resonance, such a plot should technically be possible, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top quark is heavy enough for $\rm t\to Wb$ to have both products on shell, which makes the kinematics less exciting than a true three-body decay.

Assuming you can distinguish the $\rm b$ quark from the other two, $m^2_{\rm qq^\prime}$ is a constant (at the $\rm W$ boson mass), while $m^2_{\rm qb}$ is not constant. So it just looks like a horizontal (or vertical) line, with a width just given by whatever resolution you have for reconstructing the invariant mass.